# Ошибка выполнения программы в Python

Tags: python, рекурсия, runtime

Я не понимаю, почему случается Runtime Error.
Код элементарный:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)

def Rec(n):
    if n > 0:
        Rec(n - 1)

Rec(10000)
```

PyCharm выдает такое сообщение:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Глубина рекурсии всего лишь 10000, в чем же дело?

Comment: А в какой версии python выполняете? В версии 2.7.10 - выполняется. В версии 3.4.3 - нет.

Comment: Последняя версия Python - 3.5.1

Comment: Попробуйте на 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Выдержка из документации

> sys.setrecursionlimit(limit) 
>   Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to set the limit higher when they have a program that requires deep recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

Соответственно в зависимости от платформы существует максимальное значение, которое можно передать в функцию. Полагаю у вас оно меньше ста миллионов. Будьте скромнее